# Binary in Swift

Tags: swift, binary, swift3

I'm trying to convert Binary and stuff with Swift and this is my code :

```
let hexa = String(Int(a, radix: 2)!, radix: 16)// Converting binary to hexadecimal
```

I am getting the error

> Cannot convert value type of 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: What's the declaration of `a`?

Comment: This code works if `a` is a `String` like `"10101011"`.

Comment: 'a' is an Int i have created. let a = 10

Comment: Does `a = 10` represent the number `2`?

Comment: 2 is because its going from binary to hexa which is 16

Comment: Your formula needs a `String`.  Try this: `let hexa = String(Int(String(a), radix: 2)!, radix: 16)`

Comment: @vacawama no no no no you're converting from an `Int` to a decimal `String` to an `Int` (attempting to parse it as base 2, which will crash, btw), back to an `Int`.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, it depends on what the OP is doing.  If OP is trying to convert `a = 10101011` to `"ab"`, then what I proposed works.

Comment: @vacawama you mean `a = 0b10101011`? Just need `String(a, radix: 16)`.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, sure that works.  It's just not clear what OP was asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how integers are stored.

There is no notion of a "decimal" `Int`, a "hexadecimal" `Int`, etc. When you have an `Int` in memory, it's always binary (radix 2). It's stored as a series of 64 or 32 bits.

When you try to assign to the `Int` a value like `10` (decimal), `0xA` (hex), `0b1010` (binary), the compiler does the necessary parsing to convert your source code's string representation of that `Int`, into a series of bits that can be stored in the `Int`'s 64 or 32 bits of memory.

When you try to use the `Int`, for example with `print(a)`, there is conversion behind the scenes to take that `Int`'s binary representation in memory, and convert it into a `String` whose symbols represent an `Int` in base 10, using the symbols we're used to (`0-9`).

On a more fundamental, it helps to understand that the notion of a radix is a construct devised purely for our convenience when working with numbers. Abstractly, a number has a magnitude that is a distinct entity, uncoupled from any radix. A magnitude can be represented concretely using a textual representation and a radix.

This part `Int(a, radix: 2)`, doesn't make sense. Even supposing such an initializer (`Int.init?(Int, radix: Int)`) existed, it wouldn't do anything!. If `a = 5`, then `a` is stored as binary `0b101`. This would then be parsed from binary into an Int, giving you... `0b101`, or the same `5` you started with.

On the other hand, `Strings` can have a notion of a radix, because they can be a textual representation of a decimal `Int`, a hex `Int`, etc. To convert from a `String` that contains a number, you use [`Int.init?(String, radix: Int)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/Int). The key here is that it takes a **`String`** parameter.

```
let a = 10 //decimal 10 is stored as binary in memory 1010
let hexa = String(a, radix: 16) //the Int is converted to a string, 0xA
```